# Leaflet - How to conditionally color a specific country?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have an offline Leaflet map, where the countries are drawn from a huge Javascript variable with coordinates.

index.html is as such(an example from codepen, I load the libraries locally):

```
<html>

<head>

  <title>Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

And Map.js is as such:

```
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 2);

// Huge geojson of every country, one country sample here. 
var countries =  "type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "AFG",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [61.210817, 35.650072],
                [62.230651, 35.270664],
                [62.984662, 35.404041],
                [63.193538, 35.857166],
                [63.982896, 36.007957],
                [64.546479, 36.312073],
                [64.746105, 37.111818],
                [65.588948, 37.305217],
                [65.745631, 37.661164],
                [66.217385, 37.39379],
                [66.518607, 37.362784],
                [67.075782, 37.356144]
                // .... goes on
            ]
        ]
    }
}]};

L.geoJSON(countries, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      fillColor: "#D3D3D3", // Default color of countries.
      fillOpacity: 1,
      stroke: true,
      color: "grey", // Lines in between countries.
      weight: 2
    };
  }
}).bindPopup(function(layer) {
  return layer.feature.properties.name;
}).addTo(map);
```

This produces a nice looking output, which can be seen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZNjBy

However, I wish to color potentially each country depending on an input. Let's say we open an object with the potential input:

```
let colorratio = {
    1:"green",
    2:"blue",
    3:"yellow",
    4:"red"
};
```

I then receive the following:

```
let colorinput = {
    AFG: "1",
    DNK: "2",
    SWE: "3",
    USA: "1"
};
```

Where we in layman's terms want to color Afghanistan green, color Denmark blue, Sweden yellow, and USA blue. The remaining countries should just stay at the default color value(greyish).

These abbreviations match the "ID" key in the `countries` variable.

My question therefore goes on how to approach this issue; Obviously, I need to match the keys in the huge GeoJSON file. But it's almost *13000* lines long.

Apart from that, in the `L.geoJSON` where we call the `countries` variable, we return a default color of countries. Where do I potentially access a key to color each country? Should this variable be moved into the `countries` variable for each country, as a key that is then overwritten?

I've tried looking at the Leaflet documentation and examples; but most assume that you retrieve tiles online, which is not a possibility here. It must work offline without contacting a CDN or similar - which poses some challenges, needless to say.

Comment: [Leaflet's choropleth map tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) explains how to do this, have you looked at that?

Comment: That looks very relevant, thank you. I'm reading through it right away.

Comment: That worked like a charm after a few adjustments. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: answer is : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/234343/20155

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please see [Leaflet's choropleth tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). It shows how to the `style` option in `L.GeoJSON` can be a function that returns a different style depending on the properties in the GeoJSON feature.